# Impacts of using Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase-analytics

I have been using Firebase Analytics for Android and iOS apps, but I still am not able to answer some questions:

1. How much data does Firebase Analytics send per day (considering an app that is used for work purposes during 8h/day)?
2. Does Firebase Analytics have any impact on the app performance or on the device (like battery draining)?

I have researched the Internet but still were not able to find any satisfactory answer.

I would like to know if there is any documentation that includes the measurements I am looking for or if someone has already measured these things by themselves.

Comment: Have you found any useful info? I'm also curious about this due to high load of my app itself along with quantity of data sent to firebase

Comment: Have you found any info?